# How to specify DNS name (Domain Name) prefix in Azure ASM?

Tags: powershell, azure, dns

This is the script I use to create a classic (ASM) VM in Azure

```
param(
[switch] $Help = $false,                                                      
$azurePassword,                                                               
$azureUsername ,                                                              
$azureSubscriptionName ,
$VMImageName,                                                                 
$azureStorageAccountName,
$AzureResourceGroupName,
$VMSize,                                                                      
$VMName,
$VMAdministratorUsername,
$VMAdministratorPassword,
$VNetName,
$VNetSubnetName
)

#Preparation steps
Clear-Host
$startTime = Get-Date
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "This script will create a classic VM '$VMName'"
Write-Host "Script started ($startTime)"
DetectPowershellVersion 4
$azurePassword = $azurePassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -asPlainText -Force
$azureCredentials = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $azureUsername,$azurePassword
Disable-AzureDataCollection -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

#1
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Step 1: Logging in to Azure..."
Add-AzureAccount -credential $azureCredentials | Out-Null
Write-Host "Logged in."

#2
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Step 2: Selecting subscription..."
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $azureSubscriptionName -Current
New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName $azureStorageAccountName -Label $azureStorageAccountName -Location "North Europe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $azureSubscriptionName -CurrentStorageAccountName $azureStorageAccountName
Write-Host "Selected Subscription = $((Get-AzureSubscription -Current).SubscriptionName)"
Write-Host "Selected Storage Account Name = $azureStorageAccountName "

#3
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Step 3: Locating VMImage subscription..."
$VMImage = (Get-AzureVMImage | Where { $_.Label -like "$($VMImageName)*" } | Sort-Object PublishedDate -Descending)[0]
write-host "Selected image = $($VMImage.Label)"
write-host "Selected image OS = $($VMImage.OS)"   

#4
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Step 4: Locating requested size..."
write-host "Requested size = $VMSize"
$VMConfig = New-AzureVMConfig -Name $VMName -InstanceSize $VMSize -ImageName $VMImage.ImageName 

#5 
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Step 5: Creating credentials for VM..."
if ($VMImage.OS -eq "Windows")
{
    $VMProvision = Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Windows -AdminUsername $VMAdministratorUsername -Password $VMAdministratorPassword -VM $VMConfig
}
else #Linux
{
    $VMProvision = Add-AzureProvisioningConfig -Linux -LinuxUser $VMAdministratorUsername -Password $VMAdministratorPassword -VM $VMConfig
}
Write-Host "Credentials created. Username = $VMAdministratorUsername Password = *******"


#6 Delete VM if exists
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Step 6: Deleting VM '$VMName' if exists..."
$vmstatus = Get-AzureVM -ServiceName $azureResourceGroupName -Name $VMName 
if ($vmstatus)
{
    Write-Host "VM $VMName detected."
    Write-Host "Stopping $VMName"   
    Stop-AzureVM -ServiceName $azureResourceGroupName -Name $VMName -Force
    Write-Host "Deleting VM $VMName"
    Remove-AzureVM -ServiceName $azureResourceGroupName -Name $VMName -DeleteVHD        
}
else
{
    Write-Host "VM $VMName NOT detected."
}


#7 PROVISION VM!
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "Step 7: Creating Virtual Machine in Azure..."
Write-Host "This will take a while"
Write-Host "Starting creation of VM $VMName"
Write-Host "Using VNET $VNETName and Subnet $VNetSubnetName"
Set-AzureSubnet -SubnetNames $VNetSubnetName -VM $VMConfig | Out-Null
New-AzureService -ServiceName $AzureResourceGroupName -Location "North Europe" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -WarningAction SilentlyContinue

$VMResult = $VMProvision | New-AzureVM -ServiceName $AzureResourceGroupName -WaitForBoot -VNetName $VNetName

# END
$endTime = Get-Date
Write-Host "Creation of VM $VMName finished ($endTime)"
$elapsedTime = new-timespan $startTime $endTime 
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Cyan "SUCCESS: VM Creation time = $elapsedTime"

exit 0
```

I call it with parameters (among others)

- AzureResourceGroupName "testBananas"
- VMName "testOranges"

It works ok and creates the VM as you can see in screenshot
[image]

As you can see VMName is **testOranges** and it is created in Service (Resource Group) **testBananas**.

But the DNS name is created by default to **testBananas**.cloudapp.net
I want it to be **testOranges**.cloudapp.net or anything that I specify. I think that DNS name is being populated by default.

So my question is:

**How to specify DNS name prefix in Azure ASM?**

I have found a lot of information to use a custom dns or to join it to a domain... but I don't want to do it, I just want to specify my custom DNSname.cloudapp.net because I plan to have several VM in same Resource Group

**NOTE 1**: When I execute the script I have this warning:

> WARNING: No deployment found in service: 'testBananas'

**NOTE 2**: If a create a second VM "test-Apples" the DNS name and PublicIP are the same as "test-Oranges", although the private IP is different. External SSH port for test-oranges is 55525 and for test-apples is 53456. If I SSH in both and execute "hostname" the names are matching...

Definetively there is something wrong with my script :-(

Answer (score 1):

In your #7 Provision VM! you have

```
New-AzureService -ServiceName $AzureResourceGroupName `
                 -Location "North Europe" `
                 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue `
                 -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
```

Changing `$AzureResourceGroupName` to `TestOranges` will give you the result you seek

The problem you are having is due to the fact that ASM doesn't use resource groups in the same way that ARM does. (it's use of them is somewhat inconsistent -it largely does its own thing with the names of)

Comment: ASM doesn't adhere to the concept of resource groups like ARM does, It simply creates the components you specify and uses its own logic to determine resource group names. If you want a solution based on Resource Groups you would need to use ARM